# could not run codedeployagent on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, aws-code-deploy, on-premises-instances

I am following this note: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/register-on-premises-instance-iam-user-arn.html however could not run AWS CodeDeployAgent on Windows 10 machine.

Log file:

```
2019-11-23T20:28:51 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: Version file found in C:/ProgramData/Amazon/CodeDeploy/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0.1.1597_msi.
2019-11-23T20:28:51 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
2019-11-23T20:28:51 DEBUG [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Sleeping 89 seconds.
2019-11-23T20:30:03 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: stopping the agent
2019-11-23T20:30:20 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Gracefully shutting down agent child threads now, will wait up to 7200 seconds
2019-11-23T20:30:20 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: All agent child threads have been shut down
2019-11-23T20:30:20 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(2988)]: CodeDeploy Instance Agent Service: command execution threads shutdown, agent exiting now
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

The CodeDeploy agent is not tested on Windows 10 for EC2 or OnPrem installation. Please refer to this table for supported OS list:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-supported-operating-systems-ec2
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html#codedeploy-agent-supported-operating-systems-on-premises